# Send a list to the controller using the Postman tool

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, postman

I want to send lists to the controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/contributions/photos")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public
ResponseEntity<Void> createPhotoContribution(
        @ApiParam(value = "The movie ID", required = true)
        @PathVariable("id") final Long id,
        @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> elementsToAdd,
        @RequestPart(required = false) List<Long> idsToUpdate,
        @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> elementsToUpdate,
        @RequestPart(required = false) Set<Long> idsToDelete,
        @RequestPart(required = false) final Set<String> sources,
        @RequestPart(required = false) final String comment
) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + idsToUpdate.get(0)); // NULL
    ...
}
```

using Postman https://zapodaj.net/34817fcaab172.png.html However, as it turns out, the `idsToUpdate` list is `NULL`. Why? Maybe I'm sending a list wrong?

Comment: what about the other list param? `idsToDelete` is ok?

Comment: No. Each list is NULL if I add items to it from Poostman.

Comment: What is the `[0]` for on the key? Have you tried adding that as a URL param rather than in a form or is that the format it needs to be?